# How to change or fill database name inside variable

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

In my code below I want to fill database name using input to choose one of existing databases

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost', port = '3306', user = 'root', password = '', 
database = user_input )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def choosedb():
    user_input = input("choose database name : ")
    mycursor.execute('Show tables')
    for tb in mycursor:
        print (tb)
choosedb()
```

Comment: you need to place the input statement in your `choosedb()` function too. Then  do something like `mycursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {x}')`

Comment: but i want the {x}, become a free text or base on user input. 
for ex. i have some databases like : data1, data2, & data3.

 if i run the program. then will give us a question to type the database name we want to show the tables. f.e. :

choose database name :

then we type data1, 

after that the program will showing all tables inside of that database

Comment: then you need to use `USE <db_name>; SHOW TABLES;` command like `mycursor.execute(f'USE {x}; SHOW TABLES;')`

Comment: `x` being the varible you assign the input from `input()` function.

Comment: i try to update my code, would you like to give me a suggestions. what should i do with this code. so i can reach as my want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood, you need to ask user to input the db you want to list tables from. You have already written most of the code, so here is a little improvement to your code.

```
from mysql import connector

mydb = connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


def get_input():
    # this function will keep on asking for input if the user gives in empty field
    x = input("Database name: ")
    if not x == "":
        return x
    get_input()


def choosedb():
    # using while loop is optional if you just want to run script once.
    while True:
        # you get user input here as x
        x = get_input() 
        # then query on the db server
        mycursor.execute(f"SHOW FULL TABLES FROM {x};")
        for table in mycursor:
            # then all tables are listed with table name and type and separated by TAB
            print(*table, sep="\t")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    choosedb()
```

Comment: if you just want table names and not table type etc, use `mycursor.execute(f"SHOW TABLES FROM {x};")` instead

Comment: omg, it's really works. 

thankyou so much for help me to solve this.  :)

Comment: @goleadrich please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: done brother, thankyou so much.